# SSIS Package Configuration issue with sql server data tools for visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I am using sql server data tools for visual studion 2012 for SSIS package development. Visual studio 2012 is also installed on my system. Facing issues with package configuration. I am following below steps.

1. Go to package cofiguration.
2. Expand any connection or variable to add value to config file.
3. Expand next connection or variable. And click on properties, previously selected connection values are disappearing.  But its working fine when we expand all connections, variables and then select values.

All the selected values should not disappear. it seems to be a defect. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In 2012 there is a new way to do config's. That's through project parameters. I suggest you look into it

Answer (score 0):

An old issue I know, but incase this is driving anyone else insane, there is a work around (no fix I can find yet, but then I haven't reinstalled yet either).

The work around is to expand all the properties you are going to set before setting any parameters. It appears that expanding will clear all the other settings in the wizard, hence creating the behaviour both me and the OP had.

Answer (score 0):

I found an even better workaround:

Open up 'View Code' in the Solution Explorer. This will show you the underlying XML page for the package. Find the Package Configuration value you want to change, and edit it directly.